# rsync on Cygwin: rsync: [sender] write error: Connection reset by peer (104)

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, rsync

I'm trying to rsync some files to my phone from Windows, using Cygwin. I'm trying to make it work via ssh on USB tethering as described in the comments [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/343740). I have SSHelper on my phone. My command is

```
rsync -avzHP --inplace --no-p --chmod=ugo=rwX --info=progress2 -e 'ssh -p 2222' * 192.168.1.119:/storage/emulated/0/
```

and generates an
“rsync: [sender] write error: Connection reset by peer (104)” error.

The strange thing is that it worked for a while before, to stop giving this error, and now every attempt generates the same error. What can I do?

I get analogous errors if I try via Wi-Fi.

Comment: can you stil connect with ssh ?